# Show more data Mongo/Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

Im trying to make something like youtube comments, you click 'show more' and then it loads more data (comments, images, users and other data) and show it on the page.

Im doing this:
**I have this route:**

```
router.get("/image/:id/:commentsVisible", function (req, res) {
    Images.findById(req.params.id).
    populate({
        path: 'comments',
        options: {
            limit: req.params.commentsVisible
        }
    }).
    exec(function (err, image) {
        res.render("path/to/file", {
            image: image
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div> image goes here </div>

<div class="commentAr">
    <% image.comments.reverse().forEach(function(comment){ %>
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-10 small_margin_hr">
                <strong><%= comment.author.username %></strong>
                <p class="text-left c-dark userComment more">
                    <%= comment.text %><br>
                </p>
                <span class="text-muted" style="font-size: 15px;">
                  <%= comment.date.getDate() %>\
                  <%= comment.date.getMonth()+1 %>\
                  <%= comment.date.getFullYear() %>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <% }); %>
            <form action="/image/<%= image._id %>/commentsVisible+10" method="GET">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin: 0 80%;">More</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.commentAr {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then i have a button, everytime the user click at the button it reload the page with commentsVisible + 10. It works but is kinda ugly, i wish i could just show more comments without have to reload all the page. How can i make this happen ?

Thank You.

Comment: the refresh happens on ui, nothing to do with mongodb. share your ui code

Comment: @sidgate, I added html and css codes.

Comment: don't submit the form, instead use AJAX to query more records and render it dynamically

Comment: @sidgate I've been searching for this for a long time, learning AJAX right now, Thank You !!